# How can I write (and invoke) a generic eval function in Kotlin

Tags: function, generics, kotlin, arguments

I need to write an eval function in Kotlin: so

```
eval(fn, a1,.., aN)
```

should return

```
fn(a1, .., aN)
```

as long as *a1* .. *aN* have the right types for *fn*.

So far, I have:

```
fun <ArgsType, ResultType> evalFunction(fn: (ArgsType)-> ResultType, args: ArgsType) 
: ResultType{
        return fn(args)
    }
```

This works for functions with just one argument:

```
fun square(n: Int) : Int{
    return n*n
}
evalFunction(::square, 5) returns 25
```

and

```
fun flSquare(x: Float) : Float{
    return x * x
}
evalFunction(::flSquare, 7F) return 49.0
```

But it doesn't work for functions with multiple arguments:

```
fun times(n: Int, m: Int) : Int{
    return n*m
}
evalFunction(::times, 3, 5) "has too many arguments"
```

Is there a way to allow for cases where *fn* has multiple arguments?

Comment: Not sure that's possible. How are you supposed to call a function when you don't know ahead of time how many arguments it needs? The only option is to use [varargs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)—for both `evalFunction` and `fn`—but you can't force the correct amount of arguments (i.e. the caller could pass too few or too many arguments).

Comment: It is not possible in a generic way. But if you  restrict the arguments count to a reasonable limit, you can provide a function for every count. See the bean function here:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/context/support/BeanDefinitionDsl.kt

Comment: OK. Thanks to both of you.  I'm convinced that it's not possible.  For my purposes, I can force all the functions to look like they have a single argument. With:  data class TimesArg(n: Int, m: Int) and then: fun times(args: TimesArgs){ return times(args.n, args.m)}